# Why doesn't my Ajax function work?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use a form to submit two javascript variables to a php script and return the output to a new Div on the same page via an ajax function.  It doesn't work.

here is my code

javascript/html

```
<link href="style/background.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    fbPageOptions = {
        shadowType: 'halo',
        resizeDuration: 5.5,
        imageFadeDuration: 4.5,
        overlayFadeDuration: 0,
        navType: 'both',
        width: 580,
        height: 405
    };
</script>

<body>
    <div id ="userForm">Add New User
        <br>
        <br>
        <form id ="form">
            First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"><br>
            Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" ><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        </form> 
    </div>

    <script  type="text/javascript">
        var firstname = "";
        var lastname = "";
        $('#form').submit(function() {
            firstname = $("input#firstname").val();
            lastname = $("input#lastname").val();
            alert(firstname + lastname);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "my url is in here",
                data: {firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname},
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#submitted").html(data);
                    alert("success");
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
    <br>
    <div id="submitted"></div>
</body>
```

here is the php code

```
<?php


$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
echo "First name added is $firstname";
echo "<br>";

$lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
echo "Last name added is $lastname";

?>
```

when I submit the form the alert box triggers but the div is not updated.  I'm using virtually the same code on another page and it works fine. :(  Any ideas?

Thanks so much.

Comment: What exactly does not work? The ajax call to submit the values to your php script, or the part of the javascript to write the result into the html output?

Comment: `return false` is what you need inside the submit function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return false in submit function to prevent the default behaviour of submit which is causing the problem.

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    firstname = $("input#firstname").val();
    lastname = $("input#lastname").val();
    alert(firstname + lastname);
    $.ajax({
    ......
   }); 
   return false;
});
```

Comment: just for OP info, `return false;` must to be outside $.ajax({}) function

Comment: I'm getting another error now :-/ XMLHttpRequest cannot load adduser.php. Origin http://localhost:8383 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (11:52:18:124 | error, javascript)
  at addUser.html

Comment: Scrub that , I added header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); to my php file and now it works.  thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The form submits, reloading the page, you need to prevent the default submit event :

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var firstname = $("#firstname").val(),
        lastname = $("#lastname").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my url is in here",
        data: {
             firstname: firstname,
             lastname: lastname
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("#submitted").html(data);
        alert("success");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use methods like $.param or .serialize to send you data.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: you can do : var data = $('#form').serialize() and sending data in your ajax request, it's cleaner. And for your second issues on Access-Control-Allow-Origin, it's a cross domain request issues quite popular so i think you will find quickly a solution.

Comment: Again, not sure what your getting at sorry.. :-/